# How to open pdf file in Jframe using itext

Tags: java, pdf

I would like to open a pdf file in a new Jframe. 
the pdf file exist. I just need to open it and show it in a new Jframe.
I user itext to create the pdf file. do I need the same tool to open it.
please show me how.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It is not that easy and straightforward  to open PDF inside Swing's `JFrame`. You can consider purchasing commercial tools such as [pdfviewer](http://bfo.com/products/pdfviewer/example.jsp) or use embedded browser like [JDIC](http://java.net/projects/jdic/) and display your PDF using embedded PDF Viewer (i.e. Adobe Reader) inside an embedded browser but that is tricky as well.

I would rather seriously consider opening your PDF in OS default PDF viewer using `java.awt.Desktop.open()` method which is designed to be cross-platform. Note however, that `Desktop` class is available in Java 1.6 and later.