# Generate PDF or Similar to it

Tags: java, pdf, jframe

I'm creating a JAVA application
and I want to create and display and print a PDF file.

Like this example:
http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/331702Sanstitre.jpg

 So can you give the right way to do it ?
I mean is this a pdf file displayed into a JPanel or something else ?
and thnx alot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open pdf file in Jframe using itext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256893/how-to-open-pdf-file-in-jframe-using-itext)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118635/what-is-the-best-pdf-open-source-library-for-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For working with PDF files I would recommend using a library such as [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) which has the ability to write, read, and print PDF files using org.apache.pdfbox.PrintPDF

The API can be found [Here](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.6/javadocs/)

As for displaying it in the JFrame, you can simply read the text and print it out in a Swing Text Area

Answer (score 1):

For generation of pdf files you can use [Jasper Reports library](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library). It is popular API for creation pdf files from template in which specific data is inserted. Template files have ".jrxml" extension and can be created and edited by [Jaspersoft Studio](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio). These files look like forms with variable fields, this is very useful for generating different kinds of reports.

The API for Jasper Reports Library can be found [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/).